# Intuition or rather just knowing when to use flip flops vs combinatorial vs latch always blocks

Tags: system-verilog

I understand the differences between these types of circuits, but when it comes to implementation I find myself wondering which I should use. I don't have an intuition for this yet and would like to.

An example would be helpful, so here is a question: If I am implementing a counter which would be *best* to use? always_ff, always_comb, or always_latch. From what I currently understand all of these would compile but would produce different implementations/circuits.

I come from a Verilog background and want to move into using System-Verilog more. Previously I would have used an always @ (whatever sensitivity I want) for everything and left it to the compiler/synthesis tool to decide what it was implemented as. The higher level of control that comes from always_latch, always_ff, and always_comb is appealing as I work primarily with FPGAs and resource control is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SystemVerilog constructs `always_ffcomb/latch` do not change the synthesis implementation of a block, they just enforce the synthesis coding guidelines are correct for the style you have written inside the block.

For example the Verilog code

```
always @(*) 
  if (en)
     Q = D;
```

represents a latch. You would change the `always @(*)` to `always_latch` in SystemVerilog, because that was your intent for the code. But if you had used `always_comb` that would be an error because the tool thinks your intent for the block is combinational logic, but the code inside the block represents a latch.

BTW, you should never manually specify *whatever sensitivity you want* for anything other than sequential logic. That can lead to simulation/synthesis mismatches. For example

```
always @(D)
  if (en)
     Q = D;
```

When `en` goes from 0 to 1, `Q` does not get updated with the value of `D` until it changes its value in simulation. Synthesis tool normally don't even look ant the sensitivity list unless there is a clock edge.

Comment: Thanks this is the final piece I needed to understand this thank you. Could you elaborate or point me to a resource regarding the simulation/synthesis mismatch? I have always been in the habit of specifying at least the clock or reset edge.

Comment: For sequential logic you _must_ specify a clock edge with an optional set/reset. I elaborated on the simulation/synthesis mismatch.

Comment: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf